# Sum of exponential functions involving powers of two

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, closed-form, exponential-sum

I came across a weird series with exponential functions and powers of two:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(1 - e^{-2^{-k}z} \right), z \in \mathbb R_+$$

and have no idea how to solve this (if there even is a closed form expression).  WolframAlpha tells me that the series converges (by the ratio test).

My attempts so far have been writing it as
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(n + 1 - \sum_{k=0}^n e^{-2^{-k} z}\right)$$
$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(n + 1 - e^{-z} - e^{-z/2} - e^{-z/4} - e^{-z/8} - ... -e^{-z/2^n}\right)$$
$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( n + 1 - \left(\left(\frac{1}{e^z}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{e^z} \right)^{1/2} + \left(\frac{1}{e^z} \right)^{1/4} + ... + \left(\frac{1}{e^z} \right)^{1/2^n}\right)\right)$$

which tells me that my question is ultimately about the behavior of the (diverging?) series:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{e^z} \right)^{1/2^k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty f(z)^{1/2^k}, f(z) < 1$$.

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Actually it's about the series
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1- \left(\frac1{e^z}\right)^{\frac1{2^k}}$$
Wich goes to $0$ and may (should) converge. Note that you have to use the $(n+1)$ in the partial sums (you have an error there in the first step, you get $n+1$ summands but only add $n$ to the partial sum) by putting the $1-\cdot$ into the terms of the series. Else you land at $\infty-\infty$ for the original limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$. Since $f(x)$ is a concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, for any $z>0$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}f\left(\frac{z}{2^k}\right)\leq f(z/2)=1-e^{-z/2}$$
holds in virtue of Jensen's inequality, hence the series is convergent.

In order to get a "closed form" for the series, just consider the Taylor series of $f(x)$:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}x^n,$$
from which:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}f\left(\frac{z}{2^k}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}\frac{z^n}{2^{nk}}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}\frac{z^n}{2^n-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks, the "closed form" answer you provided is great! The problem seems to have been easier than I thought.